# How to approach sqlite database of iphone calendar

Tags: iphone, calendar

guys. I'm developing iphone app. so, I want to read database of iphone calendar.
But I don't know how to read database of iphone calendar. Please tell me how to read.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has provided the [Event Kit Framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765) to access the iPhone calendar in iOS 4. Direct access using `sqlite` is not public.